# Proper Python Global Variable Use

Tags: python, global-variables

I believe I have some fundamental misunderstanding of Python global variables and their scope, and I was hoping someone can educate me.
Say I have two Python files.

```
#"GlobalSet.py"

global myVar
myVar = True

print "myVar" in globals()

import GlobalCheck
```

and

```
#"GlobalCheck.py"

print "myVar" in globals()
```

Running "GlobalSet.py" surprisingly results in

```
True
False
```

Why isn't "myVar" in the global scope within "GlobalCheck"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global in Python means global to the current module. To share variables between modules you need to import them.

Note that the global keyword in your code is doing nothing at all, since myVar is already defined at module level. You would only need to use that keyword if you were modifying the value of myVar inside a function in that module.

Answer (score 2):

The global is within the context of the module. In GlobalCheck.py, if you put

```
import GlobalSet
print GlobalSet.myVar
```

that will work. (globals() doesn't appear to work across modules.)

Comment: You can also do `from GlobalSet import myVar`

Comment: re: globals() across modules: Python doesn't have one single global scope. Rather, each module (including `__main__`) has a single module-level scope, which is what the `global` keyword in a function refers to.